# Is there any other method to find the remainder when $x+x^3+x^5+\cdots+x^{2n-1}$ is divided by $x^3-x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

A method I got from somewhere.

\begin{align}
f(x)
&=x+x^3+x^5+\cdots+x^{2n-1}\\
&= x\Bigg[\Big(x^{2(n-1)}-1\Big)+\Big(x^{2(n-2)}-1\Big)+\cdots+\Big(x^{2\times 1}-1\Big)+\Big(x^{2\times 0}-1\Big)+n\Bigg]\\
&=   x\Big(x^{2(n-1)}-1\Big)+x\Big(x^{2(n-2)}-1\Big)+\cdots+x\Big(x^{2\times 1}-1\Big)+x\Big(x^{2\times 0}-1\Big)+nx
\end{align}

As the last term $nx$ cannot be divided by $x^3-x$, the remainder is $nx$.

## My Attempt

I attempted to find another method as follows.

\begin{align}
f(x)
&=x+x^3+x^5+\cdots+x^{2n-1}\\
&= x\Big[x^{2\times 0}+x^{2\times 1}+x^{2\times 2}+\cdots+x^{2(n-1)}\Big]\\
&= x\frac{1\times(x^{2n}-1)}{x^2-1}\\
&=\frac{x(x^n-1)(x^n+1)}{(x-1)(x+1)}
\end{align}

From this, how can we find the remainder $nx$ when $\displaystyle\frac{x(x^n-1)(x^n+1)}{(x-1)(x+1)}$  is divided by $x^3-x$?

Comment: Have you defined division of rational functions? If not, there's no answer.

Comment: @Trebor: I am sorry. I don't understand your comment. Defining division of rational functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, we can eliminate a factor of $x$ , and find the remainder of

$P(x) = 1+x^2+x^4+\cdots+x^{2n-2}$ divided by $x^2-1$

Write $P(x)$ as

$P(x) = (x^2-1)Q(x) + ax + b$

Now substitute the values $x=1$, $x=-1$ to obtain

$P(1) = a+b$

$P(-1) = b-a$

and note that $P(1)=P(-1) = n $, and solve the simultaneous equations...

Comment: Actually I did it but by assuming the remainder in quadratic expression $ax^2+bx+c$. I am interested in remaining steps in my attempt. Thank you very much.

Comment: The remainder would not be a quadratic expression, however. It will be a polynomial of order 1 because $x$ divides into $P(x)$.